# Use of unresolved identifier 'metadataItems'

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

I'm getting a message from Xcode: 
*Use of unresolved identifier 'metadataItems'*

```
let items = metadataItems(from:from, withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription, keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon)
```

But the function suppose to work like this according to documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataitem/1386083-metadataitems

I need help,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a method on the `AVMetaDataItem` class so to call it, you need to do:

```
let items = AVMetaDataItem.metadataItems(from:from, withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription, keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon)
```